arsd.minigui (D) LineEdit customization
I am creating a GUI application in D using the arsd.minigui library. I need to make my widget like LineEdit, but change the background, remove border, change font, font size and alignment of text inside input field. Everything else should work like in LineEdit.
I inherited from LineEdit and created this widget:
class MyLineEdit : LineEdit
{
    private
    {
        TextAlignment _alignment;
        int _textSize;
    }

    this(Widget parent, TextAlignment alignment = TextAlignment.Left, int textSize = 16)
    {
        super(parent);
        _alignment = alignment;
        _textSize = textSize;
    }

    override int maxHeight()
    {
        return 36;
    }

    override int maxWidth()
    {
        return 200;
    }

    override int paddingLeft()
    {
        return 12;
    }

    override int paddingRight()
    {
        return 12;
    }

    override int paddingTop()
    {
        return 6;
    }

    override int paddingBottom()
    {
        return 6;
    }

    class Style : LineEdit.Style
    {
        override Color foregroundColor()
        {
            return Color.fromString("#3549FF");
        }

        override WidgetBackground background()
        {
            return WidgetBackground(Color.fromString("#3549FF"));
        }

        override FrameStyle borderStyle()
        {
            return FrameStyle.none;
        }

        override OperatingSystemFont font()
        {
            return null; //todo ???
        }

        override Color outlineColor()
        {
            return Color.fromString("#3549FF");
        }
    }

    mixin OverrideStyle!Style;
}

I override the background color and others, but when rendered on Windows 11 it looks like this:
screen my widget
Border has been removed, but the background is filled with a white rectangle. Where is it from, how can I remove it?
In addition, I don't understand how to align the text vertically and horizontally, how to change the font and its size. I want to use a non-system font (ttf), load it from memory.
In addition, I need to round the corners of my line edit. How to do this?

The style on line edit is only used with custom widgets, which isn't a very good experience on Windows... it'll feel out of place. I never implemented custom background with the native control. Might not be hard though, i can look later (I think it is a NM_CUSTOMDRAW handler needed for it). Custom widgets currently all or none, maybe i could make a class to offer that either way too. And round corners never implemented at all.. I'll have to see if i can get back to you later since right now the answer is basically "you can't" just some of it might be easy enough to do pretty soon.

I implemented a class CustomLineEdit that is available from Windows, even if using the native widgets in other places. This will give you the control you need once it is mostly debugged while still being a reasonable experience (though not quite as good as the real thing...).
With this (I'll push it to git master tomorrow probably and you can try it there) you get the blue thing with a white box in the middle. The white box is the TextDisplayHelper - an internal component of the custom widget. That might be what you're seeing in your code too if using custom_widgets. I'll fix style usage.

This commit: https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/commit/a3d532bc5a3f772ba1f741dc583df180fc28e3f7 lets you subclass CustomLineEdit instead of LineEdit and it will respect your Style overrides inside. It's not quite complete but this will get you some of what you want. For custom font change... part of the lib supports that, part ofit doesn't. The base MeasurableFont interface is implemented by custom fonts, but the widget lib only works in OSFont (which is one specific implementation of that)... idk if i wanna change it, but i'll think about it. Rounded corners also would have to DIY rn.

Thanks @AdamD.Ruppe! This is almost something I can use. For custom fonts I'm using the freetype solution for now, but I'd like to see a native solution in the future.

yeah, my tty library is half compatible here, just like... the other half is kinda important so i gotta think of how to bridge it the rest of the way. I also wrote a drawRectangleRounded function yesterday (that was harder than it seemed to get right cross platform too, but half the trouble is i was reading the docs as "start + end angle" when it was supposed to be "start angle + length"...) but it also needs some adjustments before i can publish it. so getting there but not yet.
